# how to create a date object in python representing a set number of days

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to define a variable to be a datetime object representing the number of days that is entered by the user.  For example.

```
numDays = #input from user
deltaDatetime = #this is what I'm trying to figure out how to do
str(datetime.datetime.now() + deltaDatetime)
```

This code would print out a datetime representing 3 days from today if the user entered 3 as their input.  Any idea how to do this?  I'm completely lost as to an effective approach to this problem.

EDIT: Because of how my system is set up, the variable storing the "deltaDatetime" value must be a datetime value.  As I said in the comments, something like 3 days becomes Year 0, January 3rd.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: hum, do you mean just the last day, or all the days in that range?

Comment: Note that "a date object representing a set number of days" is not a date, it's a duration or similar.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Year 0, January 3rd would be a date representing 3 days

Comment: @avorum not really... Year 0, January 3rd is a date that happens to result from adding the *duration* 3 days to an arbitrary reference date of Year 0, January 0 (whatever that is - maybe midnight before Jan 1). Depending on the exact implementation of the classes, they *might* happen to have the same numeric value, but they are not the same type...

Answer (score 10):

It's fairly straightforward using timedelta from the standard datetime library:

```
import datetime
numDays = 5   # heh, removed the 'var' in front of this (braincramp)
print datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=numDays)
```

Comment: Is `var numDays = 5` pythonic? ;)

Comment: someone's been writing a lot of javascript today :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been writing across like 5 different languages for the last few weeks, sometimes I forgot what goes with what language.

Comment: sorry, yeah, braincramp as I'm actually home sick from work ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
deltaDateTime = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
```

Comment: In my idle, python 2.7, this returns: datetime.timedelta(3), or '3 days, 0:00:00' if represented as string.

Comment: @Pawelmhm, but what happens when you add it to a `datetime` object? That's when it becomes useful.

Answer (score 4):

Use [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

days = int(raw_input())
print datetime.now() + timedelta(days=days)
```

Comment: In Python 2.7 returns: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'"

Comment: please run the code as provided. Make sure you use `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` import statement.